# Why can't I use const when returning a reference?

Tags: c++

For the sake of completeness, I want to provide me with a trivial unary `+` operator as well.
The unary operators should be immutable, I think. If I make `operator-()` return a copy of the negated object, a statement `-obj=other;` (both `obj` and `other` are objects of type `Complex`) will not compile. However, if I make `operator+()` return the object itself, another statement `+obj=other;` will compile.

The problem is I cannot use `const` in the following snippet. What does the error mean?

```
Complex& operator+() const
{
    return *this;
}
```

[image]

## Complete Code

```
class Complex
{
private:
    double re;
    double im;

public:

    // others are intentionally removed for the sake of simplicity
    Complex operator-() const
    {
        return Complex{-re,-im};
    }
    Complex& operator+() const
    {
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Comment: FTFY `Complex const& operator+() const`

Comment: You have to return a const reference: const Complex&

Comment: Your function is returning a non-`const` reference to a `const` object.   Removing `const` is not allowed since, in effect, it allows the caller of your operator to change a `const` object.

Comment: After reading the given answers, it means that I cannot chain `+obj=other` because `+obj` is now a constant object. :-) Every answer has been upvoted.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot **chain**? Usually, chaining of methods is done by using `.`. Could you please provide an example of what you consider would be chaining?

Comment: @heapunderrun: Let `a`,  `b` , and `c` be of type `Complex`. Chaining (in my terminology)  can be something like `a=b=c;` or what I want to achieve trivially above `+a=b;` or `+a=c;` or `+a=+b=+c;`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You operator is marked `const` thus the `*this` is `Complex const &`. Your return type strips the `const`.

Answer (score 2):

By declaring the function `const` , you in fact give a promise that this operation won't change the object's state .

In other words , `this` is now a const pointer ( aka a pointer to constant data ) , and thus by dereferencing it you get a `const Complex&` , something which is dropped when you assign that value to a non-const reference and thus the error .

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code to this:

```cpp
const Complex& operator+() const {
    return *this;
}
```

When declaring a method with `const`, not only are you promising you won't touch any of the **internal state** of the object, you also promise that you will not return anything that can be used to change the **internal state** of the object

Comment: I don't understand why the c++ designers made the second promise. Consumers should be able to mutate an object returned by a member function.

Comment: In other words, promising not to mutate the object's states in a member function should be orthogonal to the promising not to mutate the returned object's state outside the member function call. This is what I don't understand. :-)

Comment: @Money Oriented Programmer: a const member method should not change the state of the object, neither in the method itself, nor via the return. This is very useful, I recommend using const, where you can.